# I set a proxy in Android Studio but see a different port number in the logs than what I set

Tags: android, proxy, jcenter

I set a proxy in Android Studio but see a different port number in the logs than what I set
The exibited port number is 8580 which is the port number of my previous VPN

I have to set another VPN because the previous one does not work properly
The port for the new VPN is 61121 and I checked the connection with the **Check connection** button there and it was ok
But it seems the Android Studio is yet set with my previous VPN

Following you could see the logs and settings:

[image]

Logs:

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 7 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform leakcanary-android-2.9.1.aar (com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.9.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-aar-metadata, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Could not download leakcanary-android-2.9.1.aar (com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.9.1)
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/leakcanary/leakcanary-android/2.9.1/leakcanary-android-2.9.1.aar'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/squareup/leakcanary/leakcanary-android/2.9.1/leakcanary-android-2.9.1.aar'.
               > Connect to 127.0.0.1:8580 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution
I beleive it's a Bug in Android Studio
I changed the proxy settings in gradle.properties and the problem is solved now